# Deserialize JSON with nested categories

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, relationship, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.4

My Controller Class:

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $content = $request->getContent();

    $category = $this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($content,'AppBundle\Entity\Category','json');

    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($category);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        return new View("NAME LENGTH MUST BE >4",Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();

        return new View($category, Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
class Category
{

    private $id;
    private $parent;
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
    private $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

   //setters and getters
```

Doctrine.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
        children:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Category
            mappedBy: parent
            orderBy:
                name: ASC
  manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Category
            inversedBy: children
            joinColumn:
                name: parentId
                referencedColumn: id
  table: category
  repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
  id:
      id:
          column: id
          type: integer
          id: true
          generator:
              strategy: AUTO
  fields:
      name:
          type: string
          lenght: 255
```

When I send POST json request like this:

```
{
    "name": "Child to 8",
    "parentId": "8"
}
```

In MySQL table i do not recieve parentId:

```
mysql> select * from category;
+----+--------------------+----------+
| id | name               | parentId |
+----+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | Primary Category   |     NULL |
|  2 | Secondary Category |        1 |
|  3 | D_child            |        1 |
|  4 | F_child            |        1 |
|  5 | Z_child            |        1 |
|  6 | Y_child            |        1 |
|  7 | H_child            |        1 |
|  8 | A_child            |        1 |
|  9 | Child to 8         |     NULL |<----- must be 8
+----+--------------------+----------+
```

But after deserialization i receive this:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Child to 8"
}
```

I understand that id is an integer, but parentId is already an object of class Category. But how to make it so that he also signed up?
How can i do this? Maybe I do not understand something ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `.yml` config file for serializer. In your case - `Entity.Category.yml`.
In this file add property of nested entities, set him a type of you Entity and for be sure accessors (setter, getter).

Comment: How i can do this? `add property of nested entities`?

Comment: Did you have in output property parentId? Even if there are only scalar value.